Syntax error in Postgrestor (Node-RED): error at ','
Suppose, we have the following function in the PostgreSQL:
public | handle_val       | text             | tableid text, value numeric, vdate timestamp with time zone, error text | func
Then the following parameter incoming here (ignoring the debug nodes):

params: array[4]
    0: "60966878-WP-L_1"
    1: 60966878
    2: "2024-10-25 12:42:13+2"
    3: null

And I am trying to call the function in the Postgrestor Node like this:
SELECT handle_val( '{{{ quote_ident($1) }}}', {{{ to_number($2, '999999999999999999.99') }}}, '{{{ $3 }}}', '{{{ $4 }}}'');
I have tried many versions:

use EXECUTE format('SELECT handle_val(%I, %s, %s, %s)', quote_ident($1), to_number($2, '999999999999999999.99'), to_timestamp($3, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS+TZH'), quote_nullable($4)); - gives smth. like Bind message contains 4 parameters, but prepared statement »« requires 0
SELECT handle_val($1, to_number($2, '999999999999999999.99'), to_timestamp($3, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS+TZH'), quote_nullable($4)); - gives other syntax error: at '_'

Building the query in JavaScript seems to be recommended, but how can I execute it in the postgrestor node?
Background is that I want to use dynamic table names, therefore all the db-programming. I need to create and to fill a table for each meter, which is connected via M-Bus.
I am using https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-postgrestor-next .
